# Django filter: Many to Many specific field to custom Group field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is probably not the best way to go about user permissions- though I have a list of User Groups that contain names of Markets and a custom field built in containing the "Market_id".

Within the models I am filtering, I have a ManytoMany relationship linked to another model named "Markets". The "Markets" model also has a "market_id" field.

How can I go about giving the user only the objects that are within their "Market" or group?:

**Models I am filtering:**

```
class Opportunity(models.Model):
    opportunityid = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    market = models.ManyToManyField('Market', related_name ='market', blank= True)
```

**Market model- M2M relationship:**

```
class Market(models.Model):
    marketname = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    market_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.marketname
```

**My attempt at the queryset- currently returns a blank queryset, even though my user has permissions for all markets or groups:**

```
class projectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
   authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
   permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

   def get_queryset(self):
      user = self.request.user
      groups = user.groups.all()

      finalgroups = []

      for g in groups:
        finalgroups.append(g.market_id)

      queryset = Opportunity.objects.all()

      queryset = queryset.filter(market__market_id__in = finalgroups)

      return queryset
```

*In case it's not very clear- I am adding the User's to a generic Django User Group- these user groups have a custom field labeled "market_id". See the below screenshots for clarification:*

(Within the user page in django-admin)
[image: Within the user section]

(Within the group page in django-admin)
[image]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: how did you set the permissions?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Within the django-admin area, I manually set my User to be a part of a certain generic Group. The groups are named with the market names, and have a custom field added named "market_id"